# node.js Given a list of 98000 domain names, how to check if a domain is from shopify?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to check if a domain is built on shopify e-commerce platform?
I have searched a lot but couldn't come up with a solid approach.

I have a list of domain names in an array precisely 98000 domains. I want to check if they are using shopify as ecommerce platform using node.js code

Comment: I have a list of domain names in an array precisely 98000 domains. I want to check if they are using shopify as ecommerce platform using node.js code. I think this qualifies as a coding related issue.

Comment: It would, except that you're not asking that in your question, you just added that information in the comment.  What would be ideal is if you would ask the full question in the question, and also explain what you've already tried to do and failed at or what errors you saw.  Code examples are even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so from the [Shopify docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/connecting-domains#set-up-your-existing-domain-to-connect-to-shopify), we know that a third party domain connected to Shopify will have an A record with the IP address `23.227.38.32` and a CNAME pointing to `shops.myshopify.com`.

There might be an easier way to do it, but from the Keep It Simple perspective, I'd probably just use the node DNS module to have a gander at the IP associated with each domain and see if it's pointing at the IP address.  Note that it may take a while with 98,000, since each of these is a query to the interwebs.

```
const dns = require('dns');
const domains = require('./domains.json'); // assuming your 98,000 domains are in a local file you can pull in as JSON. 

domains.forEach((domain) => {
    dns.resolve4(domain, (err, addresses) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      if(addresses.indexOf('23.227.38.32') >= 0)
          console.log(`Shopified!  ${domain}`);
    });
});
```

This will print to console each domain that is pointing at the shopify IP.  There might be some edge case where this doesn't work (e.g. they don't actually say what happens if you *transfer* your domain, vice just connecting your domain, so I'm assuming it still uses the same base IP.